# JSF2 Myfaces tomahawk datascroller with f:ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, tomahawk, datascroller

Is it possible to have t:datascroller work with f:ajax ?

When I put a f:ajax tag inside a datascroller, the datascroller doesn't work anymore.

Maybe it is because I set the actionListener of the datascroller (not "action")... but when I set action, I get an exception saying "action can't be set".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look this example from [MyFaces Tomahawk svn](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/tomahawk/trunk/examples/simple20/src/main/webapp/dataScrollerAjax.xhtml). These are the important lines:

```
                <t:dataScroller id="scroll_1"
                    for="data"
                    fastStep="10"
                    pageCountVar="pageCount"
                    pageIndexVar="pageIndex"
                    styleClass="scroller"
                    paginator="true"
                    paginatorMaxPages="9"
                    paginatorTableClass="paginator"
                    paginatorActiveColumnStyle="font-weight:bold;"
                    immediate="true"
                    actionListener="#{scrollerList.scrollerAction}"
                    >
                <f:ajax execute="scroll_1 scroll_2 data" render="scroll_1 scroll_2 data"/>
```

That should work for most cases. If you need something more complex, adding some effects there is an example [HERE](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/tomahawk/trunk/sandbox/examples20/src/main/webapp/dataTableAjaxEffects.xhtml) that uses some sandbox components and client behaviors.

Comment: OK !
I don't know why it didn't work. I've been changing "execute" and "render" for ours. My ugly last bet was @form for all... but it didn't work.
With the scroller and the data ids like you suggest in your sample, it works.